# Unexpected space between CJK utf8 traditional chinese words in Evince or Atril, except Adobe

Tags: pdftex, cjk, chinese, evince

I made a sample of my latex notes, there're unexpected space between traditional chinese words in the item title, see e.g. in the figure I marked in the phrase “八布迦” between “八布”, similar things happens to the other items like between "八羅".

What's the reason of this space? This unexpected space could cause trouble when I want to search function of the PDF file.

**UPDATE:** It seems more likely to be associated with PDF viewer! The small space exist in Linux `Evince` and `Atril`, but with `Adobe Reader 9` and android app `WPS` and `drive PDF viewer` are normal!

**UPDATE2:** It is caused by `\textbf`, some or most of them could produce extra space between Chinese letters! I don't know why and how to solve though at the moments.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} % 10pt font size, A4 paper and two-sided margins
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=1.7cm,right=1.7cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry} % Document margins and spacings
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
%\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
%\usepackage{microtype} % Improves spacing

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for splitting text into multiple columns
%\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec} % Required for modifying section titles - bold, sans-serif, centered
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for modifying headers and footers
\usepackage{sectsty}

\chapterfont{\color{Red}\centering}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{magenta}\centering}  % sets colour of sections
%\contentfont{\color{Red}}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[unicode={true}]{hyperref}

\fancyhead[L]{\textsf{\rightmark}} % Top left header
\fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\leftmark}} % Top right header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the header
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}} % Bottom center footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the footer
\pagestyle{fancy} % Use the custom headers and footers throughout the document

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1}\ {(#2)}\ \textit{#3}\ $\bullet$\ {#4}}  % Defines the command to print each word on the page, \markboth{}{} prints the first word on the page in the top left header and the last word in the top right

\newcommand{\nam}[3]{
\vspace{3mm}
\textbf{\color{PineGreen}\Large#1}
\vspace{1mm}\\
\textbf{\color{MidnightBlue}意義： } {#2}\\
\textbf{\color{MidnightBlue}彙編： } \vspace{-3mm}{\begin{itemize}\itemsep0em#3
\end{itemize}}}

\newcommand{\name}[4]{
\vspace{8mm}
\textbf{\color{PineGreen}\Large#1}
\vspace{3mm}\\
\textbf{\color{MidnightBlue}意義： } {#2}\\
\textbf{\color{MidnightBlue}彙編： } \vspace{-3mm}    {\begin{itemize}\itemsep0em#3
\end{itemize}}
\textbf{附註： } {#4}}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{目錄}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{\Huge \textbf{\color{Red} 聖經人名地名意義彙編} \\ \huge (按筆劃排列)\footnote{\LaTeX{}排版：一起信主。印刷錯誤請聯繫\url{c275633094@gmail.com}} }
% Author
\author{\textsc{陳瑞庭}\thanks{天道出版社1988}}

%\frontmatter
\begin{document}

\CJK{UTF8}{bsmi}
%\CJKnospace
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
%\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bkai}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\chapter{聖經人名意義彙編   (按筆劃排列)}

\section{二畫}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\nam{乃縵 Naaman
}{愉快的 Pleasantness
}{\item 創46:21便雅憫之子。
\item 代上8:3-4便雅憫之孫，比拉之子。
\item 代上8:7便雅憫人以忽之子。
\item 王下5:1-19亞蘭國的將軍，曾因大痲瘋得潔淨信了真神。
}
\nam{八布迦 Bakbukiah
}{主的博施或耗費 Profusion of the Lord，被主荒廢 Wasted by Jah，主倒出 The Lord pours out
}{\item 尼11:17，12:9同所羅巴伯回國的一人，曾在聖殿管理稱謝的事。
    \item 尼12:25尼希米時一守門者。
}\nam{八羅巴 Patrobas
}{似父親的 Paternal
}{\item 羅16:14羅馬城內的一信徒。傳說他即主所差遣七十個傳道人之一，曾在部丟利為監督，後為主殉難。
}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: there's unexpected space between 八 and 布]

Comment: Where, precisely, is the unwanted space?

Comment: @egreg  sorry to confuse you, please see e.g. in the figure the cursor shows between the two words “八布”

Comment: I don't know Chinese, but I see no strange space where the cursor is.

Comment: @egreg do you think it's really a cursor that I marked in the figure? It's a space!

Comment: [This (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwLmP.png) is the picture I get.

Comment: I don't get any excess space either between  `八` and `布`, and my pdf viewer (Acrobat) experiences no difficulties when I search the pdf file for `八布`.

Comment: @Mico Your comment makes sense! **UPDATE:** It seems more likely to be associated with PDF viewer feature! The small space exist in `Evince` and `Atril`, but with `Adobe Reader 9` is suprisingly normal!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a viewer issue as mentioned in comments.